# TypeError: done is not a function when connecting mongodb to app.js (not passport)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm following the tutorial on [terlici.com](https://www.terlici.com/2015/04/03/mongodb-node-express.html) about connecting MongoDB to the rest of your web application.

I've configured a `db.js` file that reads like this:

**DB.JS:**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const state = {
  db: null
}

exports.connect = (url, done) => {
  if (state.db) return done();

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
  if (err) return done(err);
  state.db = db;
  done();
  });
}

exports.get = () => {
  return state.db;
}

exports.close = (done) => {
  if (state.db) {
    state.db.close((err, result) => {
    state.db = null;
    state.mode = null;
    done(err);
  })
  }
}
```

I then call `db.connect()` in my `app.js` file like so:

**APP.JS:**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

db.connect('mongodb-url-goes-here', (e) => {
  if (e) return next(e);

  next();
});

// cleanup
req.on('end', () => { db.close(); });

});
```

The `req.on('end'.....` line that triggers the warning in `exports.close` in `db.js`.

I'm assuming `done` is being passed in as a callback,so I'm not sure why it's returning the error message.

Also, I'm assuming the line in my code that's returning the error message is useful so it closes unused database connections.  Is this appropriate way to do this in the first place?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `exports.close = (done) => {...}` function expects a done callback to be passed to it.

But, you are not passing that callback in this line:

```
req.on('end', () => { db.close(); });
```

You could modify the close function so the callback is optional:

```
exports.close = (done) => {
  done = done || function() {};   // make sure there's always a callback here
  if (state.db) {
    state.db.close((err, result) => {
      state.db = null;
      state.mode = null;
      done(err);
  })
  }
}
```

> I'm assuming done is being passed in as a callback,so I'm not sure why it's returning the error message.

You are passing a callback elsewhere (like to `.connect()`), but not here for `db.close()`.

> Also, I'm assuming the line in my code that's returning the error message is useful so it closes unused database connections. Is this appropriate way to do this in the first place?

Yes, passing the `err` value to the completion callback is a typical way to communicate an asynchronous error value.

Comment: silly question:  for the callback to use in place of `done`, would something like `(err) => {if (err) throw err });` be appropriate?  I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of the call back is in this instance, tbh.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel - No.  It's rarely a good idea to every `throw` from an async callback.  There is typically nothing to catch or handle the `throw` anyway.  It's really up to your own coding logic to decide what should be done on an error from `db.close()`.  Probably you want to at least log what the specific error is so you can see its occurring and perhaps investigate why.  If a db fails to close properly, you may eventually run out of some sort of resource such as file handles.  There often isn't anything else that's required when a close fails.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stackoverflow.